# Continuous image of measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

I want to find a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, such that the image of this set is not measurable.

My thought was to take a nonmeasurable subset of $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and consider $A\times\{1\}$. This set has two-dimensional measure zero, and since the Lebesgue measure on the plane is complete, $A\times\{1\}$ is measurable. But if $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is the projection onto the first factor, $\pi(A\times\{1\})=A$ is not measurable. Does this example work?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Captures the essence.

Answer (score 4):

This example works — but in fact, the question itself creates too confusing impression about what is going on.  The “reality” is way trickier: there is **a homeomorphism** *f*: ℝ ⇔ ℝ which identifies a measurable subset with an unmeasurable one.

(To make an example, it is enough to identify monotonically a closed subset of zero measure with a closed subset of non-0 measure.  And this is trivial with different “flavors” of Cantor subsets.)